# How is saving a Stripe Customers Card Info in a Customer Object secure on the client side, even with tokens?

Tags: security, ionic-framework, token, stripe-payments

I want to have the customer enter their card info once and have a "pay now" button that will save the users info for future payments without them having to reenter there info and stripe says this can be done if you create them in a user object.

When the user is entering their info in and saving it in a user object where it saves on the stripe side, I dont understand how this is secure, even with tokens. Couldn't the developer add another function to go along with the stripe custom forms 'submit' or 'pay now' to send the card info somewhere else before or simultaneously while stripe is generates the token? And if I want, can I have the last four digits be displayed of their "current card" in my hybrid ionic app? Can someone please explain to me what I'm missing?

Im sending the customers payment token over the wire for a affiliate to process the payment (my apps only on the client side), and because share the token does not put the card at risk, are there any security concerns I should be aware about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a nefarious developer could easily do whatever he wants with the customer's credit card information and that would have nothing to do with Stripe. Stripe and every other payment processor assumes that its developers/clients are not using their services for malicious reasons and I'm sure if such evidence surfaced their account would immediately be revoked.

Stripe's security model allows developers to trust Stripe to store their customers' credit card numbers securely for them so that they can focus on developing their product, not worrying about building a PCI-compliant credit card database store. The idea is you hand over a customer credit card number to Stripe in exchange for a token (customer ID) which you later reference when making subsequent charges to that customer's card.

As for the last 4 digits of the card, yes that is easily obtainable via the Stripe API

https://stripe.com/docs/api#cards

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this was helpful. Im sending the customers payment token over the wire for a affiliate to process the payment (my apps only on the client side), and because share the token does not put the card at risk, are there any security concerns I should be aware about? (I also edited my question to include this)

Comment: That seems like an unusual affiliate tracking system but as long as the Stripe accounts are shared then it should work https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers. You can pass around the token in the clear, no one would be able to charge the customer's card without access to one of the shared Stripe accounts.